# How to implement Q-Learning on an array-backed grid?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, shortest-path, q-learning

I am trying to implement the Q-Learning Algorithm on a randomly generated maze that I created using `Numpy` and visualized using `PyGame`. The shape of the array is `50x50` as shown below:
[image: Maze]

- The red boxes represent obstacles (indicated with a `1`)
- The white boxes represent places without obstacles which the `agent (cyan)` can pass through (indicated with a `0`)
- The cyan box is the agent (indicated with a `2`)
- The lime box is the goal (indicated with a `3`)

The array for the above given visualization is:

```
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 3 1 0 0 0 
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

Now I need to implement the `Q Learning` method that will try to find the most optimal route between `cyan` and `lime` (considering that there is one).
I've watched a bunch of tutorials online but I couldn't find a suitable one that will help me find the shortest route according to the above given array.

I found some stuff with the `OpenAI Gym` but yet I don't know how to implement it on a array-backed grid.

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you.